# Docker container not starting in WSL

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on the WSL in Windows. I have created the folder `/mnt/c/data/db`, but then if I run

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -d -v /c/data/db/:/data/db --name testDB mongo:4.2.7
```

and wait a few seconds, then `docker ps -a` shows:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS               NAMES
5f94b01a396e        mongo:4.2.7         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 seconds ago      Exited (14) 12 seconds ago                       testDB
```

How can I correctly start this container with such a mapping?

---

Logs:

```
$ docker run -p 27017:27017  -v /c/data/db/:/data/db --name testDB mongo:4.2.7
2021-02-08T11:52:32.630+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2021-02-08T11:52:32.634+0000 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2021-02-08T11:52:32.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=f8d25a5077c4
2021-02-08T11:52:32.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.7
2021-02-08T11:52:32.636+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 51d9fe12b5d19720e72dcd7db0f2f17dd9a19212
2021-02-08T11:52:32.636+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2021-02-08T11:52:32.637+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2021-02-08T11:52:32.637+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-02-08T11:52:32.637+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-02-08T11:52:32.638+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2021-02-08T11:52:32.638+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-02-08T11:52:32.638+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-02-08T11:52:32.638+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "*" } }
2021-02-08T11:52:32.645+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2021-02-08T11:52:32.649+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=256M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2021-02-08T11:52:33.390+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1612785153:390953][1:0x7f4cbea1ab00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1612785153:390953][1:0x7f4cbea1ab00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2021-02-08T11:52:33.437+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1612785153:437153][1:0x7f4cbea1ab00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1612785153:437153][1:0x7f4cbea1ab00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2021-02-08T11:52:33.485+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1612785153:485965][1:0x7f4cbea1ab00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1612785153:485965][1:0x7f4cbea1ab00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2021-02-08T11:52:33.520+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1612785153:520251][1:0x7f4cbea1ab00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1612785153:520251][1:0x7f4cbea1ab00], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2021-02-08T11:52:33.524+0000 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2021-02-08T11:52:33.525+0000 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 1: Operation not permitted
2021-02-08T11:52:33.525+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 915
2021-02-08T11:52:33.526+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Comment: Please post the log message that you can see on console. don't put `-d` option to be able to see the logs

Comment: `/c/data/db/` or `/mnt/c/data/db`?

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1115564/905819

Comment: I created `/mnt/c/data/db`, but I read that when using the WSL I should use the `/c/FOLDER` for `/mnt/c/FOLDER`

Comment: Have you tried `-v /mnt/c/data/db...` ?

Comment: @Philippe if I do that, then it doesn't stop, but if I then do `docker exec -ti testDB sh` then `ls data/db` doesn't show any of the files from `/mnt/c/data/db`

Comment: Which version of MongoDB (Or the data files are created with) are you using locally? Error mention that the it is having issues with the data files operating with wired-tiger engine which is default in MondoDB 4.2

Comment: The fact that the container is running means definitely you should use `/mnt/c/...`

Comment: In the end I got it working using `/c/`, I just had to remove some files from `/mnt/data/db` - I don't know why those files were problematic (one was json, the other bson), but removing them meant this all worked as expected